# Show splash screen once per session with jQuery... homepage "flashing" during load

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make an intro/splash screen appear only once per session on my homepage. I do have it working with the script below but it "flashes" the homepage quickly before running the splash/intro on the initial site load (subsequent site loads do not show the div as wanted/needed)

I have a div with a class of .splash_section hidden initially & I am running the script included below.

**Question: Is there a better way to write the script, or simply a way to prevent the homepage or body from quickly "flashing" before the intro shows?**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (sessionStorage.getItem('splash') !== 'true') {
$('.splash_section').show()
sessionStorage.setItem('splash','true');
}

});
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to show that element? I am asking because trying to explain what is your final goal can provide better solution

Comment: It's literally for a splash screen intro for a client's simple brochure type site. I'm trying to convince them we don't need it, but if they are persistent then I want to do it the right way...

Comment: so you want to avoid that flash.. you can position it absolutely and put some high z-index, like 9999. This will put your element on top of any other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also hide the content of the home page initially, using css:

```
.home-page {
    display: none;
}
```

Then change your script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('splash') !== 'true') {
        $('.splash_section').show();
        sessionStorage.setItem('splash','true');
    }
    else {
        $('.home-page').fadeIn();
    }    
});
```

Comment: @shomz It's a javascript question!  Who even uses those anyway?

Comment: @Shomz so use `opacity: 0`.  Accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: I totally agree with @Shomz, you still can achieve the same but first use `.hide()` right after the `document.ready` , then show it, this way keeping the CSS untact

Comment: @Mi-Creativity In that case you're likely to get a flash of the content, which is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid...

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, it will still blink because that JS code is executed when the DOM is ready. That's why I suggested running the code right after the splash is ready.

Comment: I've done what you just said once right after the element it was for detecting if javascript disabled

Comment: Yup, it sounds the most reasonable here.

Comment: @Vince, haha, check this out - SO gave me a red message like `Stack Overflow works better with Javascript enabled`... I was messing around with something and totally forgot I had JS disabled, and that is once in like 5 years! :D At least it happened on a proper question.

Comment: @Shomz Lol, perfect timing!

Comment: I'm still laughing! :D *self-facepalm*

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.I ended up using another bit of functionality from a jquery page transition plugin that did the trick. In the end essentially putting a slight delay on the opacity of the home page did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$(document).ready` callback fires when all the page elements are parsed, your best bet is to put the splash element at the very top of the body and run the script with that function right after it. That way it will load the meta data from the head, load the splash content and display it right away before any other DOM elements are loaded.

Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="splash_section"></div>
    <script>
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('splash') !== 'true') {
        $('.splash_section').show()
        sessionStorage.setItem('splash','true');
    }
    </script>
    ...
```